# Can a scheduled future cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, memory-leaks, future

I think I have a memory leak in my Android live wallpaper. Whenever I rotate the screen, the amount of memory garbage collected increases by 50kb and doesn't go back down. I think it may be caused by a scheduled future, so I'm going to present a scenario to see if that's the case.

Let's say you have a class (let's call it Foo) that has the following members.

```
private ScheduledFuture<?> future;
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
        .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Do stuff
    }
};
```

And now you set a scheduled future

```
future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, delay, speed,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The future holds a reference to the runnable, and the runnable holds a reference to the parent Foo object. I'm not sure if this is the case, but could this fact mean that if nothing in the program holds a reference to Foo, the garbage collector still cannot collect it because there is a scheduled future? I'm not too good at multithreading, so I don't know if the code I've shown means the scheduled task will live longer than the object, meaning it won't end up being garbage collected.

If this scenario will not result in preventing Foo from being garbage collection, I just need to be told that with a simple explanation. If it does prevent Foo from being garbage collected, then how do I fix it? Do have to do `future.cancel(true); future = null;`? Is the `future = null` part unnecessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Either your `run` method relies on the enclosing `Foo` class and therefore can't live independently. In that case I don't see how you could have your `Foo` gc'ed and keep your runnable "alive" to be run by the executor
- or your `run` method is static in the sense that it does not depend on the state of your `Foo` class, in which case you could make it static and it will prevent the problem you are experiencing.

You don't seem to handle interruption in your Runnable. That means that even if you call `future.cancel(true)` your Runnable will continue to run, which as you determined could be a cause for your leak.

There are several ways to make a Runnable "interrupt-friendly". Either you call a method that throws InterruptedException (like `Thread.sleep()` or a blocking IO method) and it will throw an `InterruptedException` when the future is cancelled. You can catch that exception and exit the run method promptly after having cleaned up what needs to be cleaned up and restoring the interrupted state:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            someOperationThatCanBeInterrupted();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            cleanup(); //close files, network connections etc.
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //restore interrupted status
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't call any such methods, the standard idiom is:

```
public void run() {
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        doYourStuff();
    }
    cleanup();
}
```

In that case, you should try to make sure that the condition in the while is checked regularly.

With those changes, when you call `future.cancel(true)`, an interrupt signal will be sent to the thread executing your Runnable which will exit what it is doing, making your Runnable and your Foo instance eligible for GC.

Comment: My run method does rely on the enclosing Foo class. But when before I destroy the reference to the Foo object, what would I have to do to stop the runnable from causing a memory leak. Would `future.cancel(true)` be sufficient? I'm doing that already and the memory leak is still there. Of course, this could mean the runnable is not the source of the leak.

Comment: @gsingh2011 are you sure that `future.cancel(true)` cancels your future? In other words, can your runnable be interrupted and does it terminate its job when it is interrupted?

Comment: Since I don't understand what "can your runnable be interrupted means" I assume that it can't be interrupted. How should I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Although this question is answered long back but after reading [this](http://blog.kapsi.de/blog/canceling-scheduledfutures-memory-leak) article I thought of posting new answer with explanation.

**Can a scheduled future cause a memory leak? --- YES**

`ScheduledFuture.cancel()` or `Future.cancel()` in general does not notify its `Executor` that it has been cancelled and it stays in the Queue until its time for execution has arrived. It's not a big deal for simple Futures but can be a big problem for `ScheduledFutures`. It can stay there for seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years or almost indefinitely depending on the delays it has been scheduled with.

Here is an example with the worst case scenario. The runnable and everything it's referencing will stay in the Queue for Long.MAX_VALUE milliseconds even after its Future has been cancelled!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor 
        = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    };

    ScheduledFuture future 
        = executor.schedule(task, 
            Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    future.cancel(true);
}
```

You can see this by using a `Profiler` or calling the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()` method which will return a List with one element in it (it's the Runnable that got cancelled).

The solution for this problem is to either write your own Future implementation or to call the `purge()` method every now and then. In case of custom Executor factory solution is:

```
public static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor createSingleScheduledExecutor() {
    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor 
        = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            executor.purge();
        }
    };

    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 30L, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return executor;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain, what will happen in this scenario ? This is a SINGLE threaded executor.
If Runnable task is long running task (lets say a day) and delay and period is same as above. Does task gets queued up ? Is there a upper limit on queue for tasks ?

Answer (score 0):

> The future holds a reference to the runnable, and the runnable holds a
>   reference to the parent Foo object. I'm not sure if this is the case,
>   but could this fact mean that if nothing in the program holds a
>   reference to Foo, the garbage collector still cannot collect it
>   because there is a scheduled future?

Its a bad idea to make `Foo` some sort of transient object that you create often because you should shutdown the `ScheduledExecutorService scheduler` when your app closes. Thus you should make Foo a pseudo-singleton.

The Garbage collector understands cycles so once you shutdown `Foo`'s executor service you will most likely not have memory issues.